# regular expression for matching

Tags: regex

It is for a normal register name, could be 1-n characters with `a-zA-Z` and `-`, like

```
larry-cai, larrycai, larry-c-cai, l,
```

but `-` can't be the first and end character, like

```
-larry, larry-
```

my thinking is like

```
^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z-]*[a-zA-Z]+$
```

but the length should be 2 if my regex

should be simple, but don't how to do it

Will be nice if you can write it and pass http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/

Comment: I guess the regex is for Javascript?

Comment: Actually as Gumbo pointed below, la--rry is not allowed as well for my usage.

Thx all for all the answers, really appreciated, not only get the solution, but also lots of knowledge more on regex

Comment: @larrycai..I accidently downvoted your question..I was browsing in mobile and clicked on the button as the touch was not very accurate..I didnt know it then and now I am unable to remove the downvote..If you just edit the question, I could remove the downvote.. :P

Comment: @rubyprince: Did a little formatting edit.

Comment: @tim..thanks..I have removed the downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(-[a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

With this there need to be one or more alphabetic characters at the begin (`^[a-zA-Z]+`). And if there is a `-` following, it needs to be followed by at least one alphabetic character (`-[a-zA-Z]+`). That pattern can be repeated arbitrary times until the end of the string is reached.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: I don’t think @larrycai would want this. But if, just add the `+` quantifier to `-`: `^[a-zA-Z]+(-+[a-zA-Z]+)*$`

Comment: Just makes it worse... Now "larry" isn't allowed any more

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: What? Of course it would be matched. Note the `*` quantifier on the group `(-[a-zA-Z]+)`.

Answer (score 6):

You didn't specify which regex engine you're using. One way would be (if your engine supports [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)):

```
^(?!-)[A-Za-z-]+(?<!-)$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^           # Start of string  
(?!-)       # Assert that the first character isn't a dash
[A-Za-z-]+  # Match one or more "allowed" characters
(?<!-)      # Assert that the previous character isn't a dash...
$           # ...at the end of the string.
```

If lookbehind is not available (for example in JavaScript):

```
^(?!-)[A-Za-z-]*[A-Za-z]$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^           # Start of string  
(?!-)       # Assert that the first character isn't a dash
[A-Za-z-]*  # Match zero or more "allowed" characters
[A-Za-z]    # Match exactly one "allowed" character except dash
$           # End of string
```

Comment: Like the explanation very much, unfortunately my engine doesn't support this.

Answer (score 4):

A simple answer would be:

```
^(([a-zA-Z])|([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z-]*[a-zA-Z]))$
```

This matches either a string with length 1 and characters a-zA-Z or it matches an improved version of your original expression which is fine for strings with length greater than 1.

Credit for the improvement goes to Tim and ridgerunner (see comments).

Comment: +1, but I'd write this as `^([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z-]*[a-zA-Z])$`. Saves some anchors, quantifiers and parentheses (and is possibly more readable).

Comment: I like to put the two sides of the OR in parentheses, to make it clear, what belongs to it. I agree about the anchors, though.

Comment: Careful: Your edit has now caused the `^` anchor to belong only to the left side of the alternation, and the `$` anchor only to the right side.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. That's the reason why I like to use more parentheses than necessary, because I don't always know the precedence of the operators. :)

Comment: No! The expression: `^(([a-zA-Z])|([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z-]*[a-zA-Z]+))$` is bad! Yes, it works very well when it matches, but it will take a _long_ time to declare match failure on a non-match. (See: [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)) Always avoid expressions similar to: `[A]*[A]*` (or `(A*)*` which is even worse). You need to lose two of the three unnecessary quantifiers as Tim suggested: i.e. `^([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z-]*[a-zA-Z])$`

Comment: Good discussion and nice comments from ridgerunner/Tim, and it works for la--rry as well, thoughI didn't mention this.

and Gumbo's solution is also clean.

+1, but not set as answered

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+([-]*[a-zA-Z])*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which lazy group takes precedence..

`^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z-]*?[a-zA-Z]?$`

Answer (score 0):

maybe this?

```
^[^-]\S*[^-]$|^[^-]{1}$
```